# How to store a tree structure in Java?

Tags: java, excel, multidimensional-array, data-structures, tree

I want to create a multi dimensional array where to store a file structure recieved from an excel file, which looks something like this :

```
Folder                                  
    Subfolder01                             
    Subfolder02                             
        Subfolder02.01                          
            Subfolder02.01.01                                       
                Subfolder02.01.01.01                                
            Subfolder02.01.02                                       
    Subfolder03                             
    Subfolder04                                     
        Subfolder04.01                              
            Subfolder04.01.01                                       
                Subfolder04.01.01.01
                    Subfolder04.01.01.01.01                   
                         Subfolder04.01.01.01.01.01
                             Subfolder04.01.01.01.01.01.01   **/// 8 levels of depth**
            Subfolder04.01.02                       
                Subfolder04.01.02.01                            
        Subfolder04.02
    Subfolder04
```

What I'm trying to figure out is ***how to keep the files structure exactly as it is into an array with 8 - 9 etc levels of depth, in a smart way*** , with parents and childrens specified to the desired file.

Comment: "into an array with 8 - 9 etc levels of depth, in a smart way" <- Just my opinion, but: The smart way would be not to use arrays at all. Create your own Folder class that can have another List<Folder> to save subfolders. Then just have a Folder as your root and start filling your data structure from there.

Comment: I suggest writing your own Tree structure, don't use array in that way, please.

Comment: A Tree is a very basic data structure and a fitting data type is available in every language. Don't reinvent the wheel and *especially* dont use arrays.

Comment: Actually @f1sh - there is no generic tree type in the Java SE libraries.

Comment: @StephenC I actually just noticed that as well while i was looking for one. What an inconvenient language!

Comment: Actually, most other languages that I can think of don't have a general purpose tree type either.  Some have simple types that can be assembled into a tree ... but that's different.  (And so does Java.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is a [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) (Java example). You can create your own Classes following this pattern and write a parser (or find one) which maps to your class structure.